# Choose different versions for different files in Accurev

Tags: version-control, accurev

There is a following stream configuration:

```
PARENT-->CURRENT-->CHILD
```

Changes promoted to a `PARENT` stream broke build of each its child.
After that changes from CHILD stream were promoted to `CURRENT` stream.

Is there any way (like config spec in ClearCase) to choose only changes promoted from `CHILD` and do not take changes from `PARENT` in `CURRENT` stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create a snapshot of a parent, i.e. the new structure would be `PARENT-->SNAPSHOT-->CURRENT-->CHILD`. When the snapshot is active, it is blocking any changes to flow down. That means, anything you promote to `PARENT` will remain in `PARENT` and will not flow down to `CURRENT`.

Comment: I need not exactly this, but it makes sence. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Set a time basis on the CURRENT stream to a date before the promote transaction into the PARENT stream that broke the build.  This way CURRENT is stable and you can still promote from CHILD into CURRENT.